# UITableViewCell is resized by its content

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout

I have a UITableView, and its Cells are resized by their contents. I want the expected result :

[image]

But here is what I get on my real device :

[image]

Shortly: I want the size of the cells to fit the screen and not their content.

Thank you.

Comment: did you set up any constraints?

Answer (score 0):

In your `ViewController`:

```
var remainingSpace = CGFloat()
```

In `ViewDidLoad`:

```
remainingSpace = self.view.frame.height - //The rest of the space that other views are taking up
self.table.reloadData()
```

In `heightForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
return remainingSpace
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like the cells to be a specific height in relation to the total screen height, this bit of code would work:

```
let screenHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().fixedCoordinateSpace.bounds.height
self.tableView.rowHeight = screenHeight / (how many cells)
```

Hope this helps - Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

NO need to do it programatically, just select tableview and give its full layour constraint from Size inspector in right side menu options.

Do same for tableview cell xib or nib also.

Then select imageview and set left and above constaints and then select above label and set above, right side, and heiht middle constriant and then set third label which is in bottom to bottom and right side constraint.

Its working fine...

Answer (score 0):

Here I have tried to design your cell with proper constraint. Let me know if you still need anything else.

**1. Constraint for Image**

[image]

**2. Constraint for upper label**

[image]

**3. Constraint for lower label**

[image]